# Localization does not work for string array in android application

Tags: java, android, arrays, xml, localization

I have defined a string array in my values folder in this way for default English language

```
<string-array name="movie">
        <item>11001#Action#1</item>
        <item>11002#Animation#1</item>
        <item>11003#Comedy#1</item>
        <item>11004#Documentary#1</item>
        <item>11005#Family#1</item>
        <item> 11006#Film-Noir#1</item>
        <item>11007#Horror#1</item>
        <item>11008#Musical#1</item>
        <item>11009#Romance#1</item>
    </string-array>
```

My applicaiton is suported for many language like chainese simplified thats why i have defined another string-array in values-zh-rCN/string.xml for chainese simplified langue like this way

```
<string-array name="movie">
        <item>11001#动作片#1</item>
        <item>11002#动画片#1</item>
        <item>11003#喜剧#1</item>
        <item>11004#记录片#1</item>
        <item>11005#家庭#1</item>
        <item> 11006#黑色电影#1</item>
        <item>11007#恐怖片#1</item>
        <item>11008#音乐剧#1</item>
        <item>11009#爱情片#1</item>
    </string-array>
```

when my app is running and seleted Default english langue shown the array data but when i have seleted phone language in chainese simplified or other langue instead of english the array data does not shown. what are the possible solutionn for these problem ?

Comment: Did you find the solution ? If yes, please share the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Write your texts in `string.xml` as strings items, then use them into **arrays.xml**, example:

**string.xml (English):**

```
<string name="array_power_unit_item_00">By Watt.</string>
<string name="array_power_unit_item_01">By KiloWatt.</string>
<string name="array_power_unit_item_02">By Ampere and Volt.</string>
<string name="array_power_unit_item_03">By MilliAmpere and Volt.</string>
```

**string.xml (Arabic):**

```
<string name="array_power_unit_item_00">بالواط.</string>
<string name="array_power_unit_item_01">بالكيلو واط.</string>
<string name="array_power_unit_item_02">بالأمبير و الفولت.</string>
<string name="array_power_unit_item_03">بالميلي أمبير و فولت.</string>
```

**arrays.xml:**

```
<string-array name="arraypowerunit" translatable="false">
<item>@string/array_power_unit_item_00</item>
<item>@string/array_power_unit_item_01</item>
<item>@string/array_power_unit_item_02</item>
<item>@string/array_power_unit_item_03</item>
</string-array>
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me, after locale manual change in app settings and recreating activity I still receive strings in arrays in phone's locale. Everything else works fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
<string name="abcd">喜剧</string>
<string name="efgh">记录片</string>

<array name="array_abcd">
     <item>@string/abcd</item>
     <item>@string/efgh</item>
</array>
```

Comment: if i change this way do i need to change in jave code ? where i need to difine string array and string value ?

Comment: are you sure this is the solution for this problem ?

Comment: try this by yourself. I am sure for 110%... If this will work then accept this answer

Comment: sure . but where I need to define the array and single string . in string valie ? or  i need to define array.xml file for array

Comment: are you there now ?

Comment: both are in string file as you defined in your question

Answer (score 1):

Use this method for get resource and get array from this resource.
this will work 100%

```
public static Resources getResourcesBasedOnLanguage(Activity activity) {
    Configuration confTmp =new Configuration(activity.getResources().getConfiguration());
    confTmp.locale = new Locale("EN");
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    return new Resources(activity.getAssets(), metrics, confTmp);
}
```

Comment: This works for me, thank you. Only thing that concers me is that Resources constructor is deprecated